# Password reset issue in Cloud SQL Postgres

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-sql, postgresql-11

I am getting below error intermittently in my Cloud SQL instance,

```
UTC [2647634]: [1-1] db=postgres,user=postgres FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres""
```

After rest the password back, the process is working as usual.
Don't know which process is resetting the password. I checked the log and cant find any password resetting related log, before this issue occurred.

Comment: Is this still happening? How are you trying to connect when this happens? Is it possible that you're somehow introducing the wrong password?

Answer (score 0):

Unless log_statement is set to ddl or above, password resets would not be logged.

I would worry that you have been hacked.  There are few innocent reasons for your password to change without you changing it.